# Problem with EJB + POJO Helpers + EntitiyManager

Tags: jpa, jakarta-ee, ejb-3.0, ejb, jta

I'm working with EJBs...I do the following and I don't know why the injected EntityManager is not working as one might expect.

1. EJB1 calls a method on EJB2 that writes to the DB.
2. when EJB2 returns EJB1 sends a message to a MDB.
3. MDB calls EJB3 that reads the DB and does some work.

My problem is that the EntityManager injected in all 3 EJBs with @PersistenceContext is not working properly. Calling persist() in EJB2 is not being reflected on the EntityManager injected in EJB3.
What might be wrong?
Hope I made my problem clear enough. 
now working with Container managed transactions.

Comment: This is using JPA right? I'm not too familiar with JPA, but I suspect that each EJB is getting a different EntityManager instance. When you call persist, are you sure that it's not caching the entity and that it's committed in the database? Even if the entity is committed in the database, it may not show up in a different EntityManager instance unless you clear its cache and reload all entities.

Comment: yes, using JPA. There shouldn't be new EntityManager instances. The injection using @PersistenceContext reuses the same EntityManager isntance who's life cycle is managed by the container. Well, I believe this what happens, I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: Doesn't each EJB have its own persistence.xml file? If so, wouldn't that mean that each EJB _has_ to have its own instance of EntityManager?

Comment: sorry I believe that's not correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My problem is that the EntityManager injected in all 3 EJBs with @PersistenceContext is not working properly. Calling persist() in EJB2 is not being reflected on the EntityManager injected in EJB3.

In a Java EE environment, the common case is to use a Transaction-Scoped Container-Managed entity manager. And with such an entity manager, the persistence context propagates as the JTA transaction propagates.

In your case, I suspect you're using a `REQUIRES_NEW` transaction attribute for the method of EJB3. So:

- when invoking `EJB3#bar()`, the container will suspend the transaction started for `EJB2#foo()` and start a new transaction
- when invoking the entity manager from `EJB3#bar()`, a **new** persistence context will be created.
- since the transaction started for `EJB2#foo()` has not yet committed, changes aren't "visible" to the new persistence context.

PS: Are you really creating new threads? If yes, little reminder: this is forbidden by the EJB spec.

Comment: thanks for the answer. going to look into it. about the threads...just changed that busisness logic into a MDB avoiding the new threads...but the problem persists.

Comment: @nico As hinted, some details about the transaction attributes of the various EJB methods might help.

Comment: i think the SUPPORTS type might be suitable for my case. but, I think there's no effect going on when I change the attribute. Might this be because I have a JDBCTransactionFactory set in the hibernate config xml? should i change it to CMTTransactionFactory?

Comment: @nico Well, I think you should mention all relevant "details", like this one... And yes, I would use a CMTTransactionFactory in a Java EE context.

Comment: sorry about that. i'm new to the java EE platform and i'm discoverying it on the go. back to the problem...i have set the CMTTransactionFactory and the attributes work. but I can't get the entitymanager in the MDB to be consistent with the entityManager used to write to the DB on the statless EJB that also send the jms message on the same business method.

Comment: @nico Yes, but the MDB consumes the message in another transaction.

Comment: @Pascal Yes, that's seems more likely...since it's async it wouldn't be right to propagate the transaction. stupid me. I'm going to try a refactor and make the calls in EJB1 to EJB2 and the message sending in diferent methods to force the commit of the DB writing transaction.